# Want to show pin points in MKMapView every 5 seconds

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have three locations.  I want to show them one by one randomly in each 5 seconds.

I have used this code:

```
-(IBAction)onMap:(id)sender
{
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(loadMap)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
}

-(void)loadMap
{
    [mapView1 removeAnnotations:mapView1.annotations];

    int i = random()%3;

    location.latitude = [[lat_Array objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];
    location.longitude =[[long_Array objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue];

    CLLocationCoordinate2D center = coordinate;
    [mapView1 setCenterCoordinate:center];

    NSMutableArray *marketLocations =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    MapAnnotation *addAnnotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location];

    [addAnnotation setTitle:@"name"];

    [marketLocations addObject:addAnnotation];

    [mapView1 addAnnotations:marketLocations];

    // region.center = location;

    span.latitudeDelta = 150.0f;
    span.longitudeDelta = 150.0f;

    region.span=span;

    [mapView1 setRegion:region animated:FALSE];
    [mapView1 regionThatFits:region];
}

#pragma mark - Mapview delegate
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *annView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"MyPin"];

    annView.animatesDrop=FALSE;
    annView.canShowCallout = YES;
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

    //annView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

    return annView;
}
```

It shows the locations correctly but in each load, it focuses to Africa from user's scroll.

I don't want that. I just want to remain in the point where the user scrolled to.

Comment: You should not set region each time if you want to be at one place and drop your pins out there.

Comment: @Vish: Then how can i set region when location change?

Comment: Your question says that you want to remain at one point when annotations are added.

Comment: @Vish: Actually my requirement is when I load next coordinates,then also I want to remain in the region where the map view gets scroll down.

Comment: Sorry but what are you trying to say with mapview gets Scroll Down! please explain.

Comment: You call setCenterCoordinate with `coordinate` but what is it initialized to?  If it's 0,0 then that's in the Atlantic Ocean just southwest of Africa.  Then later you call setRegion with `region` but what is  `region.center` set to?  Again, if it's 0,0, the map will be centered off the southwest coast of Africa.

Comment: Also note the line `[mapView1 regionThatFits:region];` **does nothing**.  The `regionThatFits:` method _returns_ a region and since the line does nothing with the return value, the line is pointless -- remove it.  Calling `setRegion` automatically does a "fit" itself.

Comment: @Anna: Thanks... But i don't want to focus to any centre at each interval.

Comment: @Anna: I just want to show the region which is focusing just before the loading.

Comment: If you don't want to move the map every 10 seconds then take all the lines about changing the map's region out of `loadMap` which is called every 10 seconds and put it into a function that is only called once.